# How does Blender interpret Collada files (.dae) for rigging?

Tags: graphics, blender, collada

I'm interested in creating a tool that parses Collada files and supports rigged 3D models for animation and interaction. How does Blender interpret a Collada file (and rigging in general)?

Any resources on computer graphics and rigging would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find documentation on the collada file format at [The Kronos Group](https://www.khronos.org/collada/).

Blender uses the [OpenCollada library](https://github.com/khronosGroup/OpenCOLLADA) to import and export collada files.

If you want to start with something a little lighter you can have a look at the [collada exporter](https://github.com/godotengine/collada-exporter) made by the developers of the godot game engine.

Comment: Thanks for the Collada specs resource. Right now, I'm just working with one file, so my parser doesn't need to be super inclusive of every part of the collada schema. Do you know how a rig controls a mesh, or to better phrase it: once the controller data is parsed, how does a computer graphics application manipulate a mesh using that controller data.

Comment: In blender, vertex groups link a bone to the verts. As you move a bone, any vertices in a group with the same name as the bone get a matching transform, proportional to the group weight assigned each vert.